# Entity-Framwork-4 - accessing foreign key property when context is gone in ASP.NET MVC2 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have a database with this table:

```
Customer
- ID
- Phone
- Cell
- Fax

PhoneList
- ID
- PrefixID
- Number

Prefix
- ID
- Number
```

There is a FK between Customer each phone columns to PhoneList ID (and another one from prefixID to ID on table prefix)

I've imported the DB into edmx file using VS2010.
I got PhoneList, PhoneList1, PhoneList2 properties - generated (**Q1: how to I change this to other names ?**)
In an ASP.NET MVC Model class library I get the customer list using:

var customers = from c in context.Customers select c;

and send the result to the controller:

return customersTable.AsQueryable();

The problem- I can access all the regular properties of Customer in the VIEW, but once accessing the PhoneList (auto generated that represent the phone number object) I get this error - as the context is long gone and closed on the model side:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

**Q2: How should I deal with this situation - How can I make sure the data I need "Stays" / Retreived from the Database (and on the other side, other FK which I don't need to be loaded -doesn't get loaded)**

(Q2- is the "Real" question, answer on Q1 will be appreciated...)

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC2, EF-4

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use Entity Framework classes inside your views. You should define and use view models. View models are classes which are specifically designed for the needs of a given view. Thus you might have multiple view models from the same model (view models are a subset of the model) or a single view model which is mapped to multiple model classes (in this case the view model is a superset of multiple models). So basically you would have a repository which will take care of fetching the model from somewhere (database, file, remote service, ...) and then convert this model to a view model and pass this view model to the controller.

So in your repository you could [eagerly load](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/13/eager-loading-child-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx) child entities to avoid getting this sort of exceptions.

You would then decorate your view model classes with the necessary display attributes which would be specific to the given view. You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to convert between your models and view models.

Comment: q: viewmodels should be defined in the UI project. when populating the viewmodel - wouldn't I be facing the same problem ? If I understand correctly the 2nd part of your answer, should I create a model class to every EF class and then populate it and pass it instead of the auto-generated class and these classes will be the subsets of my viewmodels ? isn't this a "waste" of the auto generated model I've got from EF ?

Comment: @Dani, yes view models should be defined in the UI project as they are tied to a view. You should create a view model which is specific to the needs of the view and pass this view model instead of the EF class. And no this isn't a waste of auto generated model classes.

Comment: @Darin, To be sure I understand - I need to define a model class in the model project, populate it with data from the Auto-Generated Class that I get from linq, send this class to the UI, and there I will put it inside a view-model which serves my view needs. so I have one customer class from the edmx, one customer class that I manually created in the model project, and then I'll have the last class inside the viewmodel for that specific view. is this the right way to go ?

Comment: @Dani, no it's not right, suppose you have an autogenerated Employee EF model with Id, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate and a ton of other properties. Now you have a view which requires you to display only the salary formatted as currency and the full name of the employee. In your UI layer (MVC application) define a EmployeeViewModel with the following properties: Salary, FullName and decorate the salary property with the necessary display format attributes. In your controller Use AutoMapper to perform the conversion between Empployee and EmployeeViewModel and pass the view model to the view.

Comment: @Darin -Another Q. - would I be able to update the object as it is no longer linked to it's original object retrieved by EF ?

Comment: @Dani, sure you could have a bidirectional mapping with AutoMapper.

Comment: @darin - I think you lost me... my problem is when the employee class has a address property which is a reference to another class. that 2nd class is not accessible in the view (either direct or in VM) b/c the contex of the EF when I got the employee class is no longer available in the view. if I had accessed myEmployee.Address.City in the model - it would have worked. but not in the view. (other employee.name - properties pass ok as there are not referencing another class).

Comment: @Dani, you are not following me. In your view you don't have to write `myEmployee.Address.City`, it's too long and boring. If your view needs to display the city of the employee you would directly have a City property in your view model so that in your view you simply `<%: Model.City %>`, you get the point? View Models. Don't pass some complex EF objects and then write spaghetti code in your view. Let the controller do the necessary mapping and the view will be so much fun.

Comment: @Dani, the view should never fetch data from a database (lazy loading), the view is there to display data which is being provided by the controller. It's the controller which defines the boundary for laziness at your data access layer, not the view.

Comment: @darin - I believe the same problem will arise at the controller level - as the class with the reference is passed from the model, and once the controller get the employee class, the context is disposed, and the referenced data is no longer accessible.

Comment: @Dani, did you read the [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/13/eager-loading-child-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx) I've linked to in my answer? Did you see the `Include` method?

Comment: Hi - So it was the include - but this is a very poor solution, losings intellisense and going back to strings to represent objects....

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You should be able to edit the names with the editor that opens in Visual Studio when you double-click the EDMX file.

Q2:  Either keep the context open (if that's an option), or use the Include method that is accessable to you (don't remember if it is off IDbSet or ObjectQuery.

Comment: Thanks, About Q1 - when I update the EDMX due to DB changes, will these manual changes stay ? about Q2- it would be wrong to keep the context open.... I'll lookup what include method means..

Comment: After saying "keep the context open" I should have put "but be sure properly clean it up when you are finished.  If you were using IoC, this would make more sense.  About QA1: One of the main purposes of EF is to not require your object model to match your database model, so this should be very possible.  The EDMX essentially contains the shape of your objects, the shape of your database model, and a mapping between the two.